# Where to store the private key and the public key in a communication protocol

Tags: public-key, protocol-design, key-exchange

I want to create a simple secured connection protocol over TCP/IP.
I just want to connect from my mobile device to a server securely.

Firstly I thought to use an SSL connection, but I changed my mind and decided to create my own protocol.

I am thinking about key exchange: where I should put the private key, and where I should put the public key.

In SSL, the private key is stored on the server, and the public key is sent to the client.
But in an SSH connection, the private key is stored on the client, and the public key is sent to the server.

In my situation, the program on the mobile device will be public. Anyone can use it. (It isn't only for my use.)

And I am interested in the advantages of storing the private key or the public key on the server. Why should I do one or the other?

Comment: "*And i decided to create my own protocol about that.*" what motivated this change of mind? Generally, it's very dangerous and irresponsible to invent your own crypto protocol.

Comment: I think custom protocol is unknown to cryptanalyst. And for this reason , it will be more secured. 
And SSl protocol is very flexible , and has many cihpers . 
I want to create custom protocol which will use one symmetric chiper and for key exchange RSA will be used . 
And this custom protocol will not be flexible . 
I dont invent anything :) i will use ssl protocol scheme i think , but i think about to store private keys where . 
In that situation i think to store private key in server. But i dont know advantages or disadvantages of it

Comment: Secure protocols are designed to be secure even if they are known. Security through obscurity is not real security, at least not in the cryptographic sense. However, you are right that the flexibility of SSL/TLS is a valid security concern (in the sense that it complicates both the protocol and the implementations). Many existing SSL/TLS implementations will allow you to restrict the set of allowed protocol versions and cipher suites. Do that, and ISTM you will have accomplished what you want.

Comment: "And for this reason , it will be more secured" a protocol that wasn't analyzed is much more likely to have undiscovered weaknesses than one that has been analyzed a lot. So this argument makes no sense.

Comment: "I think custom protocol is unknown to cryptanalyst. And for this reason , it will be more secured." If the protocol is unknown to cryptanalysts, then there is no way to know how secure it is. By contrast, SSL was carefully constructed by industry experts to be as secure as humanly possible and has been extensively analyzed and tested. The odds that you implement something more secure than SSL are essentially zero. Most likely, it would turn out to be horribly broken (as early versions of SSL turned out to be).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Implementing something better than SSL isn't *that* hard. SSL suffers quite a bit from bad legacy constructions that lead to vulnerabilities like BEAST or Lucky13.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sure, you can take SSL and improve it by removing legacy issues, but then it won't be better because it's "unknown to cryptanalyst". It will be better because it is based on structures that are very well known and well understood. And I'd still worry about the risk that you'll create new, and much more serious, vulnerabilities.

Comment: Sorry men , I didn't know my new protocol creating idea is very bad for you . 
I agree with you , if protocol is unknown to  cryptanalyst it is not more secured. you are right!

Comment: But , it is also not less secured if that is unknown to crytanalyst , i think . 
I don't want to create more secured protocol than ssl , i mentioned in my question . SSL is most secured protocol , i agree with you . But SSL is flexible , problem is in that situation . 
SSL is used in browsers and other programs for secured connection , and for this , it is very flexible . 
But in my situation , i have one client program , and one server program .  I don't want flexibility, more chipers , difference encryption methods . 
I want to use one symmetric ciphers and one key exchange algorythm.

Comment: I have two choice. 
1) to modify ssl or to use ssl with less flexible , e.g. in ssl connection client can only use aes for encryption . client have one cipher and one way to authenticate , so on. 
2) to create new protocol . 
In that situation , i thought that . to modify or to use strong configured ssl is too hard . 
Which do you advice me ?

Comment: @TalehIbrahimli: Honestly, your reasoning is so unbelievably disconnected from reality that you have no business choosing or implementing a security scheme. I'm not trying to be mean, I'm trying to protect you (and anyone who relies on your software) for disaster. If you find using SSL properly too hard, you have absolutely no business attempting the much, much harder task of implementing the encryption scheme itself, much less designing one.

Comment: @TalehIbrahimli: To give you an analogy, think of a guy building a suspension bridge to carry trucks who says, "The design of other suspension bridges is too complicated for me to understand and customize, I'll just design a bridge from scratch." Would you drive over that bridge?!

Answer (score 2):

[Don't roll your own crypto.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology/2210#2210)

[Use preexisting protocols and libraries whenever possible.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/at-what-level-of-abstraction-should-a-developer-work-with-with-regards-to-crypto) If there hasn't been any cryptanalysis on your protocol, that makes it *less* secure, not more. Recommended protocols are recommended because they underwent a lot of cryptanalysis and they resisted.

[If you think SSL isn't right for you, you're probably just not using it right.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/how-to-roll-my-own-security-mechanism-avoid-ssl)

Your mobile device and your server already have SSL implementations. Concentrate on using it correctly.

Your comparison of SSH and SSL shows that you don't really understand what's going on. Specifically, with SSH, there are two unrelated key pairs in play: the one for server authentication (private key on the server, sent to clients and stored there), and the one for user authentication (private key on the client, stored on the server before it can be used). (The client machine's private key can also matter but only when doing host-based authentication which is quite rare.) See [What is the difference between authorized_key and known_host file for SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-key-and-known-host-file-for-ssh/20710#20710) for a more detailed explanation. In the case of SSL, there is no user authentication, only authentication of the server machine (and optionally of the client machine, but that's not normally done when you browse an https website).

The server will have a private key. Your mobile device needs to have the corresponding public key to ensure that it's talking to the right server. You can include the key with your application, but make sure you're able to update the key in case you want to connect to a different server. If the server needs to authenticate the mobile device or the user of the device, you will need to have a private key on the device, or a password, or some other authentication mechanism.

Understanding these aspects is the really important part. Figure out who needs to authenticate with whom, who should trust whom and who can trust whom. This will tell you which public keys you need to copy or validate. Use SSL, and make sure you use it right: the devil is in the [public-key infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure).

I may already have mentioned this, but: [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own), mmkay?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're doing this for fun, and to learn a thing or two about programming crypto primitives in practice. To answer your question I believe the public key should stay on the mobile device but if you're using multiple clients then you may need multiple key pairs. As others have pointed out, chances are you won't end up with much security. In any case post your final protocol here or on Security.SE (make sure you follow question guidelines though) and these guys will take it apart ;)

Comment: And to make myself clear I'm not trying to discourage you from writing your own protocol, quite the contrary. Just don't rely on it for anything serious and you'll be fine.